# Open URL while app launch in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, url, uiwebview

I need to open an URL while application launch. But i wrote code inside viewcontroller. It taking time to open URL in safari. I don't have splash screen, so it load black screen long time

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com/"]];

}
```

How to reduce the time and open URL fast.

Comment: Why would you launch Safari when a view controller is being loaded?

Comment: I get that. But why do it when loading a view controller? That makes no sense.

Comment: Is i need to write inside AppDelegate?

Comment: Describe the problem you are trying to solve. You state you want to launch Safari when the app launches. Why? What's the point of having a native app that does nothing but launch Safari?

Comment: this is client need. that's all

Comment: No because you haven't described the problem you are trying to solve. Until you do that, no one can offer any good suggestions.

Comment: client need to open their website URL while app launch. If we have icon for every app. Once click the app icon it automatically load their website url. I used UIWebView, but it doesn't responsive. So, they need to open in safari

Comment: Apple won't accept such an app. It doesn't do anything. A user can simply have a bookmark in Safari or a shortcut on their home screen.

Comment: the solution you taken for this case is not the right solution. i suggest you to find another solution

Comment: Yes. But they need to do. If i open in webview it doesn't responsive. What can i do?

Comment: @manujmv: shall i use UIWebView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of adding url in `ViewDidLoad` method

You can try to add in this method

```
-(id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) 
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com/"]];
    }

    return self;
}
```

Comment: This is just as pointless as doing it in `viewDidLoad`. Why would you switch to another app just as you create a new view controller?

Comment: After closing app then app it doesn't open the  safari. Is need to use Application does not run in background: YES in plist?